# Is my understanding about [basic.link]/7 in N4140 correct?

Tags: c++, c++14, linkage

[VS2015](http://rextester.com/SPRTS22276) compiles and executes the following snippet without a problem. g++ and clang don't link the code, and I think they are correct.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace X {
    void p() {
        void q();   // This is a block scope declaration of the function q() with external
                    // linkage (by §3.5/6), which then must be defined in namespace X,
                    // according to §3.5/7, and not in the global namespace.
        q();
    }
}

void q() { std::cout << "q()" << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    X::p();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is almost identical to the one in [basic.link]/7 - Yes, your interpretation is correct.
Using an undefined function `q` renders your program ill-formed **NDR**. Hence VC++ is *technically* conforming. However, you definitely want to report it.

Note how VC++ [produces the same output](http://rextester.com/YGN61305) ("q()") even if we add an inner definition of `q`:

```
namespace X {
    void p() {
        void q();                    
        q();
    }

    void q() { std::cout << "This would be right"; }
}

void q() { std::cout << "q()" << '\n'; }
```

…but does have sensible behavior [when `extern` is used](http://rextester.com/LRDREU41282).

Comment: Why NDR? Shouldn't the linker report an error in this case?

Comment: @Belloc The implementation should but isn't required to.

Comment: Where did you get this NDR from?

Comment: @Belloc [basic.def.odr]/4.